# React Router isActive doesn't work for child route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following router

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route name="events" path="/events" component={Events}>
    <Route path=":eventId" component={Details}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

and the following link: `<Link to={'/events'}>`
When I browse `/events/1234`, `this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to, true)` returns **`false`**.

I also tried with this configuration, but it's the same:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route name="events" path="/events" component={Events}>
  <Route path="/events/:eventId" component={Details}/>
</Route>
```

and also tried `<Link to={'events'}>` (without the `/`) but no more success.
Any idea how to get `isActive` to **`true`** when browsing `/events/1234`?

Comment: child needs to be configured this way ```<Route path="/events><IndexRoute /><Route path="/:eventId /></Route>```

Comment: This doesn't work: `Location "events/1246" did not match any routes`. Though, if I remove the `/` `<Route path="/events"><IndexRoute /><Route path=":eventId" /></Route>` the routing works but isActive is still *false*